# How does one read a file using the Scoped Directory Access permission system?

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to access my SD Card on Android 7.0 (Samsung S7) and I found that this is a possible way to get permission for it: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access

I wrote the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent sdCardIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        StorageVolume sdCARD = null;
        for (StorageVolume volume : sm.getStorageVolumes()) {
            if (volume.getDescription(this.getApplicationContext()).equals("SD card")) {
                sdCARD = volume;
            }
        }
        if (sdCARD == null) {
            return;
        }
        sdCardIntent = sdCARD.createAccessIntent(null);
        startActivityForResult(sdCardIntent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Access sd card?
    }
}
```

When run, I get the permission prompt and it seems to work since I get the event in onActivityResult but I haven't found how to access any file or directory on the SD card.

Do I have to use the URI I get from the Intent result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to use the URI I get from the Intent result?

Yes. That `Uri` should represent a document tree, and so you can use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` on that tree. From there, you can iterate over the contents and get `Uri` objects to individual pieces of content. Use a `ContentResolver` and its `openInputStream()` method to read in any such piece of content.

However:

- Please do I/O on background threads
- If you wish to pass the `Uri` to another component (e.g., activity, service), even within your own app, be sure to include `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The two extra pointers are quite helpful too.